# Using Drupal::url()

Tags: 8, uri

I am porting code from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8.

In Drupal 7, my code looks like the following:

```
return url($parts[0] . '/' . $parts[1] . '/profile/id/' . $context['profile']->uuid . '/cancel');
```

I know that I have to use [`Drupal::url()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal.php/function/Drupal%3A%3Aurl/8), but I have to use a route name or an external URI, but I don't know what to pass.

How should I update my code for Drupal 8?

Comment: kiamlaluno, what part of porting my code to Drupal 8 is not clear to you?

Comment: I edited my question, I hope it's clear as water to you.

Comment: I think you have to tell us, where do you want to put this code, what function is this and what you want to return. The code you are using now looks like drupal 6, and you don't want keep this in drupal 8.

Comment: I think that the question is "How do I create a dynamic Url from a menu router item that I can use in a link (or possibly in a redirect)?"

Comment: return Url::fromRoute('your_route_name', ['profile' => 123'])) assuming the parts 0 and 1 are not entities or some sort of placeholders. If so then they would be part of that second argument.

Comment: A single line of code is not sufficient to answer the question. You already know what `Drupal::url()` requires. How can we tell you the route name without knowing where that line is used, and which parameters the hook/function is using?

Comment: I agree with kiamlaluno here; we need to know the bigger context of where/how you are using this.  BTW, Drupal::url() is deprecated; you should really use one of the static factory methods, like Drupal::createFromRoute().

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```
$path = '/' . $parts[0] . '/' . $parts[1] . '/profile/id/' . $context['profile']->uuid . '/cancel';
$url_object = \Drupal::service('path.validator')->getUrlIfValid($path);
$url_object->setAbsolute();
$url = $url_object->toString();
```